# Regular expression for matching HH:MM time format in Java

Tags: java

I want a regular expression to match time in HH:MM format. This is what I have and it doesn't work:

```
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("/^(0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$/");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(hora);
        
        if(matcher.matches()) {
            isHour = true;
        }
```

I tried this but it keeps giving me false

```
public static boolean isHour(String hora) {
    boolean isHour = false;
    
    try {
        
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("/^(0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$/");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(hora);
        
        if(matcher.matches()) {
            isHour = true;
        }
        
    }catch(Exception e) {
        
        logger.error("error isDate boolean", e);

    }
    return isHour;
}
```

Any solution or if I have generated my regex incorrectly? thank you

Comment: I tried to fix your code formatting. Either intent all your lines by four spaces *or* surround with a pair of triple back-tick characters.

Comment: By the way, instead of regex,  you might consider simply using [`LocalTime.parse`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalTime.html#parse(java.lang.CharSequence))

Comment: Remove the slashes.

Answer (score 3):

Using `java.time`

```
private static boolean isHour(String hora) {
    try {
        LocalTime.parse(hora);
        return true;
    } catch (DateTimeParseException dtpe) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice alternative to regex. Also, the formatter is optional. One could simply use `LocalTime.parse( input )` while trapping the exception to detect faulty input.

Comment: good point, updated :)

Comment: In almost all cases, I'd prefer something like this, as regular expression can't validate the value on validate the format

Answer (score 2):

> *"... I want a regular expression to match time in HH:MM format. ..."*

In *Java*, the leading and trailing `/` characters are not used.

Try the following pattern.

```
(?:[01]\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]\d
```

Here is an example, where *s* is the *String* value.

```java
boolean b = s.matches("(?:[01]\\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]\\d");
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```java
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public static boolean isHour(String hora) {
    boolean isHour = false;

    try {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(hora);
        
        if (matcher.matches()) {
            isHour = true;
        }
        
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // log the error using your logging mechanism, e.g., Logger
        logger.error("error isHour boolean", e);
    }
    return isHour;
}
```